# node js application refreshing browser

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

Normally node js applications do not refresh the web browser when navigating to pages, just changing url and content without browser refresh.
But my express js application refreshing every menu click. 
I am using mysql backend.
What is the issue. I am not hosted this application. Now development stage.
Now it look like php application.

Comment: I think you should look at express router

Comment: Node.js doesn't automatically make single-page applications. You need a frontend framework for that, it has nothing to do with the backend.

Comment: Please check this site: https://www.noon.com/en-ae/ not refreshing on page navigation

Comment: @SKMedia and how is that website relevant to your question? You can create a website that does not do _refreshing_ with any server-side technology (no matter if it is php, nodejs or even plain html documents). The part that makes your website not referesh is client side javascript.

Comment: "Normally, light switches don't flush toilets, but my toilet flushes when I start my car.  I made chocolate chip cookies yesterday.  What is the issue?  I don't have a driveway.  My toilet looks like a bicycle."  Does that question make any sense?  This is essentially how your question reads.  You need to break down your problem in to separate pieces and understand the real layers here.  Node.js has nothing to do with what happens client-side.  Try to do some basic debugging first, organize your question, and try again.

Answer (score 0):

You have to understand the difference between front-end and back-end technologies. Front-end is all about what the user/browser sees and does. All the browser understands is html, css and javascript. The browser is programmed to navigate using anchor tag links (`<a></a>`) by sending a new `GET HTTP` request to the server on the new URL. This is the refreshing you see. NodeJS has **nothing** to do with the user experience. That's what happens on the server and how that request is handled. To create a single page application you need to work on that on the front-end. Specifically javascript. You don't need a server to create a single page application. The reason you might have thought that this is the job of nodeJS is because you might have seen some **MEAN** stack tutorials. Those include mongoDB as the database, express the the backend framework, angularJS as the front framework (this is what makes your application a single page) and node as the runtime.

Recommended frameworks / libraries for creating single page applications are:

- VueJS: https://vuejs.org/ ( Recommended for beginners )
- Angular: https://angular.io/ ( Opinionated framework )

Comment: Vue also is for enterprise application and you are not forced into such a strict structure like with angular. So depending on the use-case Vue can be a much better choice, even for enterprise application.

Comment: Well I could write over 10 paragraphs analyzing frameworks. This guy is a beginner so all I did was clear his mind on what actually makes a website an SPA. Feel free to edit the answer.